# Days of the week probability question

Tags: probability

Consider 3 events and their probabilities:

Probability that today is Friday: $P(F)= \frac{1}{7}$
Probability that today is Saturday: $P(S) = \frac{1}{7}$
Probability that it is the weekend: $P(W) = \frac{2}{7}$

I know the probability that it is Friday or the weekend is just $P(F)$+$P(W)$. But, if I wanted to find the probability that it is Saturday or the weekend which are overlapping events, can  $P(S \cup W)=P(S)+P(W)-P(S \cap W)$ be used? Because when I think about it, $P(S \cap W)$ should be $\frac{1}{7}$ but $\frac{1}{7}$ is not equal to $P(S) * P(W) = \frac{2}{49}$. Is there a fundamental rule I'm overlooking?

Comment: Remember that two events $A,B$ are *mutually exclusive* iff $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Two events being mutually exclusive then implies that $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ however for the general case you usually have $Pr(A\cup B)\neq Pr(A)+Pr(B)$.  Instead the general identity is $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$.  In a similar vein, $A$ and $B$ are said to be *independent events* iff $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  In the general case however it is often that $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  Instead the general identity is $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B\mid A)=Pr(B)\times Pr(A\mid B)$.

Comment: *Tldr:* some of the formulas you think you learned only apply in special circumstances and don't apply here.

Comment: $Pr(S\cup W)=Pr(S)+Pr(W)-Pr(S\cap W)=Pr(S)+Pr(W)-Pr(S)Pr(W\mid S)=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{7}-\frac{1}{7}\times 1 = \frac{2}{7}$

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It clearly shows effort and it's properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

$P(S \cap W)$ is only equal to $P(S) * P(W)$ if the events $S$ and $W$ are independent, but in this case $S$ and $W$ are not independent.